# Regex: find occurrence of a digit in a string

Tags: regex, grep

Problem: I want to match those strings which contains two digits.Their position is random and a digit should match 2 times.

Example for better understanding my question:

```
3abc3 
a22de
b7abc7a
```

For these strings it must match.If a string contains two digits but they are different then it shouldn't match.

Example:

3abcd2 not supposed to match
3abc3 -> supposed to match

I tried using {n}, but it not helps, because it thinks the two number follows each other.

Comment: `^.*(\d).*\1.*$` Use a capturing group to find the first number, and then refer to that capturing group again.  [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/LZTJVl/1)

Comment: I am using regex with egrep

Comment: digit I should correct that

Comment: Yes, they should match with all of your examples.And I already said we are looking for digits not numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `grep`:

```
grep -E '([0-9]).*\1' file

3abc3
a22de
b7abc7a
```

About this Regex:

```
([0-9]) # match and capture any digit in group #1
.*      # match 0 or more of any character in between
\1       # using back-reference \1, make sure we have same digit as in group #1
```

Comment: This is answered fast.And what Aaron said is right you should change that.

Comment: I think 3a0c3 will match with this regex, and it should not.

Comment: If it shouldn't match `3a0c3` then OP should clarify. If you don't want to match `3a0c3` then use `grep -E '([0-9])[0-9]*[^0-9]*[0-9]*\1' file`

Comment: It should match for examples what I given at the moment. It is all about to understand how they work and what is the correct order of meta characters !